# Gstreamer opusenc encoder produces distorted/choppy audio

Tags: gstreamer, opus, mediasoup

I am using the following gstreamer pipeline to grab RTMP src and transcode it with opusenc encoder and sending it as rtp packet to Mediasoup (a webrtc library).

```
gst-launch-1.0 \
  -v \
  rtpbin name=rtpbin rtp-profile=avpf do-retransmission=true \
  rtmpsrc location=rtmp://3.126.121.45:1935/live/qonda-injecttest-orig \
  ! flvdemux name=demux \
  demux.audio \
  ! queue \
  ! decodebin \
  ! "audio/x-raw,channels=2,rate=48000" \
  ! audioconvert \
  ! opusenc \
  ! rtpopuspay pt=101 ssrc=11111111 \
  ! rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_1 \
  rtpbin.send_rtp_src_1 ! udpsink host="3.69.236.199" port="41269" sync=true \
  rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_1 ! udpsink host="3.69.236.199" port="48143" sync=false async=false
```

But this produces very choppy/distorted audio. A sample [here](https://bemivirtuell.sharepoint.com/:u:/s/GoQonda/EdWIwIrkUXdBvRuw83Xk4xUB2vTYFaEhqU8f9CwgH1i9zg?e=ib1cz7).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution that solves the problem. So Answering my own question.

I think it's more related to mediasoup (WebRTC framework that I am using) which uses OPUS which is set to `channels=2 & rate=48000` but opusenc in gstreamer can use channels 1 or 8. Setting a sample rate of 24000 solves the problem.

Just need to add the following line before opusenc:

```
! audioresample ! audio/x-raw, rate=24000
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a stereo audio interlacing problem, where every other sample is being skipped.  Your provided output sample is a stereo MP3, yet both channels are identical.

Try using `channels=1` or playing with or removing `demux` processing.

Comment: Tried setting `channels=1`, doesn't help. And can't really remove the demux processing as I am also sending video.